# Laplace Transform Non-homogeneous System with Arbitrary ICs?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

> Use the Laplace transform to solve the system $$\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y' \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-2 &1 \\  1&-2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
> 2e^{-t}\\3t \end{pmatrix} = Ax + g(t)$$
>
> Instead of using zero initial conditions, let $$X(0) = \begin{pmatrix}x(0)\\y(0) \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1 \\  \alpha_2 \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> where $α_1$ and $α_2$ are arbitrary.
>
> How must $α_1$ and $α_2$ be chosen so that the solution is identical to
>
> $\begin{pmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t)  \end{pmatrix} = c_1\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}e^{-3t} + c_2\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}e^{-t} + \dfrac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}e^{-t} + \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}t e^{-t} + \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}t-\dfrac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix}4\\5\end{pmatrix}$

I can solve the Laplace transform of a non-homogeneous linear system just fine when there *is* an actual initial value with actual numbers, but this is difficult to solve.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @E.G: If you use Laplace transform with arbitrary constants, you get $$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \dfrac{1}{2} e^{-t} (a+b+4)+\dfrac{1}{6} e^{-3 t} (3 a-3 b-4)+e^{-t} t+t-\dfrac{4}{3} \\
 \dfrac{1}{2} e^{-t} (a+b+2)+\dfrac{1}{6} e^{-3 t} (-3 a+3 b+4)+e^{-t} t+2 t-\dfrac{5}{3} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ Compare that to the given solution and realize that you can just combine constants to make arbitrary constants. I used section $24.3$ of https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~novozhil/Teaching/266%20Data/lecture_24.pdf to do these calculations.

Comment: Note that in my previous comment $$\alpha_1 = a, \alpha_2 = b$$

Comment: The step I'm most confused on is this - after you multiply the inverse matrix (SI - A) with (yo + G(s)), how are you going to do partial fractions with the alpha constants?

Comment: For example, how do you find the inverse Laplace Transform of $$\dfrac{a}{s-1}$$ $a$ is just a constant, just like in this problem. I can even write a constant as $a + b +7 - 3c + 8h$, but it is still just a constant.